# Making GTK file chooser list directories on top (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, gtk

Since upgrading to Xubuntu 16.04, in the file chooser directories are mixed with files which is annoying. How can I make it list the directories on top, as in previous versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

When you open your file chooser, right-click in a free space in the row containing *Name*, *Size*, *Modified*, etc. And then tick *Sort Folders before Files*.

[image: File chooser sort oder]